# Make Locust Wait Between Task Runs

Tags: python, rabbitmq, locust

I am using Locust to push messages into a RabbitMQ queue. I'm able to do this easily using the RabbitMQ sample from the [locust.io-demo](https://github.com/jamescarr/locust.io-demo) repository, but now I need to force the single task to wait 1 minute between each invocation.

In my test, I need to push 100 messages into a queue every minute since this system will receive messages in "bursts" in one-minute increments. I've tried implementing this but have been unsuccessful. Here's the first thing I tried:

```
from rabbitmq import get_client
import time

from locust import Locust, TaskSet, task, events

class RabbitTaskSet(TaskSet):
    @task
    def publish(self):
        get_client().publish()

class MyLocust(Locust):
    task_set = RabbitTaskSet
    min_wait = 30000
    max_wait = 30000

def on_locust_stop_hatching():
    get_client().disconnect()

events.locust_stop_hatching += on_locust_stop_hatching
```

I assumed that the `publish` method would be executed once every 30 seconds since that's what the value for the min and max wait times. I then started Locust with 1 user and a hatch rate of 1.

What I saw was that a new request was being generated every 10 seconds in the Locust UI.

I then tried this instead:

```
class RabbitTaskSet(TaskSet):
    @task
    def publish(self):
        get_client().publish()
        time.sleep(30)

class MyLocust(Locust):
    task_set = RabbitTaskSet
    # min_wait = 30000
    # max_wait = 30000
```

I then started Locust again with 1 user and a hatch rate of 1. Oddly enough I saw the same results - 1 new request every 10 seconds. Heck I even tried using `gevent.time` instead of `time.time` but I still got the same results.

How can I make my publish task wait for 30 seconds between each execution? Is there a property that I'm missing?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392451/locust-how-to-make-locust-run-for-a-specific-amount-of-time

Comment: Thank you for the quick response bumblebee but I don't want to stop the entire test. I want my taskset to wait for 30 seconds before executing. I want all users to run the task set at the same time and then wait 30 seconds before running again.

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/59#issuecomment-41624517

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
from rabbitmq import get_client
import time

from locust import Locust, TaskSet, task, events,between

class RabbitTaskSet(TaskSet):
    @task
    def publish(self):
        get_client().publish()

class MyLocust(Locust):
    task_set = RabbitTaskSet
    wait_time = between(5000, 10000)


def on_locust_stop_hatching():
    get_client().disconnect()
```